# What is the difference between a criteria, a predicate, and a specification?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In the [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications), a criteria is defined by:

> Writing a criteria you actually define the where-clause of a query for a domain class.

Specifications and predicates seem to have the same role.

What is the difference between a [criteria](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html), a [predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html) and a [specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html)?

Answer (score 43):

### Criteria

The **Criteria** API was added in JPA 2.0. According to the [Java Persistence wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria):

> The Java Persistence Criteria API is used to define dynamic queries through the construction of object-based query definition objects, rather than use of the string-based approach of JPQL.

A [`CriteriaBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) is used to build a [`CriteriaQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) objects which is then used to perform a query such as in this example from the [Java Persistence wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria):

```
// Query for a List of objects.
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root employee = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(employee.get("salary"), 100000));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Employee> result = query.getResultList();
```

### Predicate

The [**`Predicate`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html) class is part of the Criteria API and is used to construct where clauses. Such as in this modifed example taken from the [Java EE 7 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria003.htm):

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.name), "Fido");
Predicate predicate2 = cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.color), "brown");
cq.where(predicate1.and(predicate2));
```

### Specification

The [**`Specification`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html) interface is defined by the [Spring Data JPA project](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/). According to the following blog post, [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/), from Oliver Gierke:

> To be able to define reusable Predicates we introduced the **Specification interface** that is derived from concepts introduced in Eric Evans’ [Domain Driven Desig book](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly).
> A Specification can be defined such as:

```
public static Specification<Customer> customerHasBirthday() {
    return new Specification<Customer> {
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.equal(root.get(Customer_.birthday), today);
      }
    };
  }
```

and then used in a [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html).

```
List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll(customerHasBirthday());
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

NOT from API Docs but as I see it:

`Criteria` is an abstract concept, kind a collection of `Predicates`. `CriteriaQuery` has all the `Criteria` set as `Predicate`s.

As `Criteria` is a plural of `Criterion` might say that `Predicate` equals to `Criterion`.

Spring `Specification` is meant to be implemented to provide means to use [`specification pattern`](https://dzone.com/articles/java-using-specification) when constructing `CriteriaQueries`.

Feel free to correct me with - preferably API- documentation.